# JOOQ for multiple profile

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

Recently I have started using jooq as db layer for my java projects. Here is my organization, we have different DB name for our application database (That's DevOps pipeline).

Please consider the following info:

- Let's say my application name is **MY_APPLICATION**.
- Let's say **MY_APPLICATION** uses database  **MY_DB** (That's MySQL based and it has some table inside it).

Let's consider the following information for deploying **MY_APPLICATION**:

- Whenever we will deploy in dev profile, our original MY_DB will become DEV_MY_DB (Only DB name got to change, Tables are same).
- Whenever we will deploy in the stage profile, our original MY_DB will become STG_MY_DB.
- Whenever we will deploy in production profile, our original MY_DB will become PROD_MY_DB.

I want to achieve **MY_DB** code generation from JOOQ at build time (via Jenkin build job). If I am building **MY_APPLICATION** on dev profile, JOOQ should generate DB classes for schema name **DEV_MY_DB**. Similarly for stage and prod.

Here is JOOQ code generator utility  I am using .

```
  public static void init(String p_catalog_name, String p_schema_name, String p_db_username,
  String p_db_password, String p_db_url) {

Target l_target = new Target();
l_target.setDirectory("IdeaProjects/paas/css/src/main/java");
l_target.setPackageName("com.myorg.paas.css.db.entity");
Configuration configuration =
    new Configuration()
        .withJdbc(
            new Jdbc()
                .withDriver("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                .withUrl(p_db_url)
                .withUser(p_db_username)
                .withPassword(p_db_password)
        )
        .withGenerator(
            new Generator()
                .withDatabase(
                    new Database()
                        .withName("org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase")
                        .withIncludes(".*")
                        .withExcludes("")
                        //.withInputCatalog(p_catalog_name)
                        .withInputSchema(p_schema_name)
                        .withForcedTypes(
                            new ForcedType()
                                .withUserType("java.time.LocalDateTime")
                                .withConverter(
                                    "com.paas.css.startup.jooq.TimestampToLocalDateTime")
                                .withExpression(
                                    "created_at | updated_at | start_date "
                                        + "| end_date | start_time | end_time | "
                                        + "next_trigger_start_at | next_trigger_end_at")
                                .withTypes(".*"),
                            new ForcedType()
                                .withUserType("com.paas.css.utils.DefaultMap")
                                .withConverter(
                                    "com.paas.css.startup.jooq.ObjectToJsonMapConverter")
                                .withExpression(
                                    "running_days | transaction_details |  "
                                        + "| reward_details | triggers  | life ")
                                .withTypes(".*")))
                .withTarget(l_target));

try {
  GenerationTool.generate(configuration);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println();
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Can anyone please help me to archive this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this type of multi tenancy in three ways:

#### Generate code for each environment

You can re-generate your schema for every environment. This way, your jOOQ code will always reference the environment on which it is currently being run. This may be a bit brittle, as you will be testing different code from the code that you're shipping into production

#### Remove the schema information in the code generator

You can tell the code generator not to generate any schema information in your generated code by using the [code generation schema mapping feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping):

```
.withInputSchema(p_schema_name)
.withOutputSchemaToDefault(true) // That's it
```

The generated code will now produce unqualified table names. This approach assumes that you use different JDBC connections / URLs on each environment that accesses the correct database.

#### Map the schema information at runtime

By using the [runtime schema mapping feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-render-mapping/), you can translate the schema names of all your generated code at runtime for each environment.

The generated code will now produce qualified table names with the mapped schema qualification.